# How can I solve this Integral?(complex variables)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$\displaystyle{\int_{C}}{\frac{e^z}{z^3}}dz$, where $C(t)=2e^{2\pi it}+1+i$, and $0\leq t\leq1$

I'm a bit confuse with this integral, the thing is that at the moment I saw it, I though I could use the Cauchy Integral formula, but the thing is that in order to applied the Cauchy Integral Formula zero has to be in the interior of C. So I don't really know what to do, I also though in using the Cauchy-Goursat theorem but it was the same problem.

I really appreciate any advice or suggestion you can give me, perhaps I'm just using the theorem in wrong way.

Thanks so much

Comment: The sole pole of the integrand is at $0$, which is certainly inside the contour, as $1 + i$ is only a distance $\sqrt{2}$ from the origin, whereas $|C(t) - (1 + i)| = 2 > \sqrt{2}$. (Of course, if there were no pole inside or on the contour, and the integrand is analytic on some simply connected open set containing the contour, then the CIF would still apply, and would simply tell us that the integral is zero.)

Answer (score 1):

The parameterized curve is a circle centered at $z=1+i$ with radius $2$, so the singularity of the integrand, $z=0$ is inside $C$.

Cauchy's integral formula (general version) shows that
$$
\int_C \frac{e^z}{z^3}\,dz = \frac{2\pi i}{2!} (e^z)''\Big|_{z=0} = i\pi.
$$